# Find the function rule of $g(z) = \int_{\alpha} \frac{w^3 + 2w}{(w-z)^3} dw$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $\alpha$ a simple closed curve of class $C^1$, and traverse (counterclockwise). We define. $g: \mathbb{C}-\{\alpha\} \to \mathbb{C}$ as:

\begin{align}
g(z) = \int_{\alpha} \frac{w^3 + 2w}{(w-z)^3}dw
\end{align}

I want to find the function rule of $g$.

Here is my work:

Consider $f(w) = w^3+2w$. Then $f'(w) = 3w^{2} + 2$; $f''(w)=6w$.

Using the Cauchy Integral it follows:
\begin{align}
f''(z) &= \frac{2!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\alpha} \frac{w^3+2w}{(w-z)^{2+1}}\\
\pi i f''(z) &= \int_{\alpha} \frac{w^3+2w}{(w-z)^{3}}\\
6 \pi i z &= \int_{\alpha} \frac{w^3+2w}{(w-z)^{3}}\\
\end{align}

$\therefore g(z) = 6 \pi i z$

I know this only works inside the $\alpha$ region, but $g$ is also defined outside. What should I do to find the function rule outside $\alpha$ region? Any suggestion?

Comment: If $z$ lies outside region bounded by $\alpha$ or in the unbounded component of $\alpha$ then $g(z)=0$ by Cauchy's theorem as (assuming $z$ is not on $\alpha$ ) as the integrand would be an analytic function in the region bounded by $\alpha$